# Check if at least one record have a given attribute set to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

Two models:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subtasks

end

class Subtask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task

end
```

Subtask have boolean attribute that set to true if subtask is complete.

How can i check if a task has at least one completed subtask?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest possible thing would be

```
task.subtasks.where(:completed => true).exists?
```

If you define a `completed` scope on subtasks this could be shortened to

```
task.subtasks.completed.exists?
```

Both of these will fire a database query, so if you already have the subtasks loaded (`task.association(:subtasks).loaded?`) it will probably be quicker to manipulate the ruby objects via somethig like

```
task.subtasks.any? {|subtask| subtask.completed?}
```